# Eclipse: Maven project builder generating NullPointerException when building workspace

Tags: eclipse, nullpointerexception, m2eclipse, workspace, eclipse-mars

I'm using STS, with the following version info

```
Spring Tool Suite 
Version: 3.7.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 201506290652
Platform: Eclipse Mars (4.5.0)
```

I have imported a number of Maven projects.  When Eclipse is automatically building my workspace, this dialog will pop up

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'myproject'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

When I look in my workspace/.metadata/.log file, I see

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 75 2015-07-28 08:40:07.418
!MESSAGE Errors occurred during the build.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.m2e.core 4 75 2015-07-28 08:40:07.418
!MESSAGE Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'ebook'.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.resources.VirtualComponent.setReferences(VirtualComponent.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.WebProjectConfiguratorDelegate.setModuleDependencies(WebProjectConfiguratorDelegate.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.WTPProjectConfigurator.mavenProjectChanged(WTPProjectConfigurator.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.mavenProjectChanged(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1000)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.notifyProjectChangeListeners(ProjectRegistryManager.java:783)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.applyMutableProjectRegistry(ProjectRegistryManager.java:919)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:299)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.getProjectFacade(MavenBuilder.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:245)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:300)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:303)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:359)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

I have no idea what this means or how to fix it.  Help is appreciated, - Dave

Answer (score 2):

Removing `.settings` folder and re-importing Maven project solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Outline", scroll down select "projectxlmns", scroll to "parent org.springframework.boot".

Then

- select lookup parent from repository
- right click
- select maven
- update project

This solved my problem in sts

[image]